# Check connectivity to internet, hangs UI with bad signal

Tags: android, exception, wifi, httpconnection

I'm trying to check `connectivity(WIFI or cellular)` to `internet`with this method called from `OnStart` method:

```
public static Boolean isInternetConn(Context ctx){

        ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        boolean connected= false;
        if((wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting())){   

            try {

                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();             
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                URL myurl = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                URLConnection connection;
                connection = myurl.openConnection();
                connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(2000);
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                int responseCode = -1;
                responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                      connected = true;
                      httpConnection.disconnect();
                }
                else {
                    httpConnection.disconnect();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();                
            }
        }

      return connected;
    }
```

If the net signal is low the method hangs the UI and sometimes the UI becomes to black.
I've configured the timeouts to a low value and the problem still happening.
It's recommende to do this task in Async Task?

Thanks

Comment: use handler with progress bar..... ur are interrupting main Ui thread

Comment: All length operations should be done off the Main Thread. AsyncTask provide such class. `AsyncTask` is recommended, there is nothing to recommend here. if it is a task done off the UI tread it means you have to use Thread class or specialize classes. Android provide such specialize class named `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to ping google to check your network connectivity. This is unnecessary and doing network operations on main thread will disrupt your UI. Use the following method instead:

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Remember to add `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` and `INTERNET` permissions in your manifest

**EDIT** : To check the quality of network, use [this](https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class) library created by facebook. It categorizes connection quality into poor (below 150 kbps), moderate (between 150 and 550 kbps), good (between 550 and 2000 kbps) and excellant (over 2000 kbps).

Comment: This returns TRUE if the WIFI or cellular connectivity is connected but doesn't check if the internet connectivity works fine